# Python List of Ngrams with frequencies

Tags: python, nltk, scikit-learn

I need to get most popular ngrams from text. Ngrams length must be from 1 to 5 words.

I know how to get bigrams and trigrams. For example:

```
bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
finder = nltk.collocations.BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(words)
finder.apply_freq_filter(3)
finder.apply_word_filter(filter_stops)
matches1 = finder.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 20)
```

However, i found out that scikit-learn can get ngrams with various length. For example I can get ngrams with length from 1 to 5.

```
v = CountVectorizer(analyzer=WordNGramAnalyzer(min_n=1, max_n=5))
```

But WordNGramAnalyzer is now deprecated. My question is: *How can i get N best word collocations from my text, with collocations length from 1 to 5. Also i need to get FreqList of this collocations/ngrams.*

Can i do that with nltk/scikit ? I need to get combinations of ngrams with various lengths from one text ?

For example using NLTK bigrams and trigrams where many situations in which my trigrams include my bitgrams, or my trigrams are part of bigger 4-grams. For example:

bitgrams: **hello my**
trigrams: **hello my name**

I know how to exclude bigrams from trigrams, but i need better solutions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**update**

Since scikit-learn 0.14 the format has changed to:

```
n_grams = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 5))
```

Full example:

```
test_str1 = "I need to get most popular ngrams from text. Ngrams length must be from 1 to 5 words."
test_str2 = "I know how to exclude bigrams from trigrams, but i need better solutions."

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

c_vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 5))

# input to fit_transform() should be an iterable with strings
ngrams = c_vec.fit_transform([test_str1, test_str2])

# needs to happen after fit_transform()
vocab = c_vec.vocabulary_

count_values = ngrams.toarray().sum(axis=0)

# output n-grams
for ng_count, ng_text in sorted([(count_values[i],k) for k,i in vocab.items()], reverse=True):
    print(ng_count, ng_text)
```

which outputs the following (note that the word `I` is removed not because it's a stopword (it's not) but because of its length: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20743758/):

```
> (3, u'to')
> (3, u'from')
> (2, u'ngrams')
> (2, u'need')
> (1, u'words')
> (1, u'trigrams but need better solutions')
> (1, u'trigrams but need better')
...
```

This should/could be much simpler these days, imo. You can try things like [`textacy`](https://textacy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#textacy.doc.Doc.to_bag_of_terms), but that can come with its own complications sometimes, like initializing a Doc, which doesn't work currently with v.0.6.2 [as shown on their docs](https://textacy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#textacy.doc.Doc). [If doc initialization worked as promised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51431112/), in theory the following would work (but it doesn't):

```
test_str1 = "I need to get most popular ngrams from text. Ngrams length must be from 1 to 5 words."
test_str2 = "I know how to exclude bigrams from trigrams, but i need better solutions."

import textacy

# some version of the following line
doc = textacy.Doc([test_str1, test_str2])

ngrams = doc.to_bag_of_terms(ngrams={1, 5}, as_strings=True)
print(ngrams)
```

**old answer**

`WordNGramAnalyzer` is indeed deprecated since scikit-learn 0.11. Creating n-grams and getting term frequencies is now combined in [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer). You can create all n-grams ranging from 1 till 5 as follows:

```
n_grams = CountVectorizer(min_n=1, max_n=5)
```

More examples and information can be found in scikit-learn's documentation about [text feature extraction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction).

Comment: If you don't want TF-IDF normalization just use: `CountVectorizer(min_n=1, max_n=5).fit_transform(list_of_strings)`.

Comment: but what do i do next ? how do i get ngrams frequencies ?

Comment: @twoface88: `v = CountVectorizer(min_n=1, max_n=5); X = v.fit_transform(["an apple a day keeps the doctor away"]); zip(v.inverse_transform(X)[0], X.A[0])`. Note that stopwords and one-char tokens will be removed by default.

Comment: For `CountVectorizer` "DeprecationWarning: Parameters max_n and min_n are deprecated.  use ngram_range instead.  This will be removed in 0.14"  So, `CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 5))`

Comment: In the latest version sklearn changed the format to
`n_grams = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 5))`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to generate the raw ngrams (and count them yourself, perhaps), there's also `nltk.util.ngrams(sequence, n)`. It will generate a sequence of ngrams for any value of *n*. It has options for padding, see the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/util.html I think under the hood nltk.util.bigrams() and nltk.util.trigrams() are implemented using nltk.util.ngrams()